# How to require a field depending on the http method ?

Tags: swagger, swagger-2.0

I am trying to write a [JSON API](http://jsonapi.org/) using swagger and I'm facing some problem because some fields are required or not depending on the method used.

Here are a line from the update specs

> The resource object MUST contain type and id members.

and here one from the create specs

> The resource object MUST contain at least a type member.

So currently I have

```
Customer: 
    title: Customer
    type: object
    required: ["id", "type"]
    properties:
      id:
        type: string
      type:
        type: string
      attributes:
        type: object
        properties:
          name:
            type: string
          address: 
            type: string
```

What I would lke to do is having `required: ["id", "type"]` for `patch` method but only `required: ["type"]` for `post` method. Is it possible to do it without redefining another Customer ?

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve that using the below method:

```
  Customer: 
    title: Customer
    type: object
    required:
      - type
    properties:
      id:
        type: string
      type:
        type: string
      attributes:
        type: object
        properties:
          name:
            type: string
          address: 
            type: string
  Customer_patch: 
    type: object
    required:
      - id
    allOf:
      - $ref: '#/definitions/Customer'
```

You have to redefine Another Customer to put the additional required fields but you can reuse the actual Customer definition object.

Comment: Has this not been fixed by now? Surely practical to have this work-around +1, but not ideal by far.